# JSTL foreach 2 list

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I have 2 list coming from a servlet  and I am able to print the names now how can i send id to other page? names list has name1 and name2 and id has 1 & 2,i need to send particular id for a name..

```
<%request.getAttribute("names")%>
 <%request.getAttribute("id")%>
 <c:forEach items="${names}" var="Childnames">
```

`<li>< a href="example" /a>${Childnames}</li>`

```
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it easier if you put your id as a key and name as values in a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map (for storing names and id's) then add this map to ArrayList. and sent to second page.